# Public key f3:6e:87:04:ea:2d:b3:60:ff:42:ad:26:67:17:94:d5 blacklisted (see ssh-vulnkey(1)); refusing to send it

Tags: ssh

I'm reproducing the Debian PRNG vulnerability from 2008 in a lab environment. Now I'm trying to SSH into the machine, but every time I try to send the private key I get:

```
Public key f3:6e:87:04:ea:2d:b3:60:ff:42:ad:26:67:17:94:d5 blacklisted (see ssh-vulnkey(1)); refusing to send it
```

Is there a flag I can give SSH to ignore the fact that this key has been blacklisted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following string to the ssh_config:

```
UseBlacklistedKeys yes
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the `openssh-blacklist` package:

```
apt-get remove openssh-blacklist
```